# Can't acces files on Precise

Tags: 12.04, permissions, file-properties

I have 12.04 installed on my laptop. I am the admin of the computer, but every time I try to change file permissions to access files or tick execute file as program then it just changes back quickly or unticks the box quickly.

I am really desperate! Please help.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu and what is the path to the file you want to change permissions for?

Comment: I installed it from dvd. And the path to the file... can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

First try, from the command line:

```
chmod 777 file_name_here.txt
```

This will set everyone to access everything (a huge security risk) so only do it with one file.

If you get errors about a read only file system, then your file system is read only and that is another problem.